# Token Mismatch Exception in VerifyCsrfToken.php

Tags: laravel

I am getting this error on submit button click.

I already tried to put following code in form tag :

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

**session.php**

```
<div class="title">
    Laravel Session Tutorial

   <form action="about.php" method="post">

       {{ csrf_field() }}
       <input type="text" name="name" value="">
       <button type="submit" name="button">Enter</button>         
   </form>
</div>
```

I am just passing input string to another web page. For example, if I input name in textbox. In return, it gives me that input name in another web page like  "Hello , (name)".

Comment: don't set your action in the form to a .php file, set it to a route from web.php

Comment: I suspect you need to rename `session.php` to `session.blade.php`, so the `{{ }}` template instructions actually get executed. I'll bet if you view source they're there un-executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<div class="title">
    Laravel Session Tutorial
   <form action="about.php" method="post">
       {{ csrf_field() }}
       <input type="text" name="name" value="">
       <button type="submit" name="button">Enter</button>         
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited but it still gives me error. @Aneesh Ajithkumar

Answer (score -1):

You have to write

`@csrf` or `{{ csrf_field() }}`

instead of

```php
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And then run following.

```php
php artisan make:auth
php artisan optimize
```

Comment: `@csrf` and `csrf_field()` are just shortcuts to do the same thing. `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">` is fine.